# Why can't I block the Internet access (iptables)?

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I am setting up my linux server's firewall with iptables.
for test, I failed to protect the the local web server(8080 port) from Internet accessing.

- OS
  OMV6(6.0.16-1) a debian based linux
- connections:

```
                    Internet
                        |
LinuxServer(pppoe)----Router(pppoe-relay)
                        |
WorkPC------------------+
```

- the interfaces

```
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:c4:cf:2e:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20e:c4ff:fecf:2e98/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1454 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp
    inet x.x.x.x peer x.x.x.x/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- What I did

1. I added rules to drop all input packet from ppp0:

```
root@lxs:/home/aaa# iptables -L INPUT -vn
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3625 packets, 1238K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4513  638K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0
  460 25241 DROP       all  --  ppp0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

2. montoring the packet. In the same time access the web server(8080 port) from LTE:
   `x.x.x.x` is the ip address of `ppp0`.

```
root@nas:/home/bjn# tcpdump -i ppp0 -n port 8080
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), snapshot length 262144 bytes
15:59:20.474424 IP 133.106.52.47.65368 > x.x.x.x.8080: Flags [S], seq 1901489667, win 65535, options [mss 1300,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 3868697852 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
15:59:20.474678 IP x.x.x.x.8080 > 133.106.52.47.65368: Flags [S.], seq 3559979952, ack 1901489668, win 65160, options [mss 1414,sackOK,TS val 3483431673 ecr 3868697852,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:59:20.542349 IP 133.106.52.47.65368 > x.x.x.x.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 4105, options [nop,nop,TS val 3868697925 ecr 3483431673], length 0
15:59:20.558901 IP 133.106.52.47.65368 > x.x.x.x.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:598, ack 1, win 4105, options [nop,nop,TS val 3868697927 ecr 3483431673], length 597: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
15:59:20.559000 IP x.x.x.x.8080 > 133.106.52.47.65368: Flags [.], ack 598, win 505, options [nop,nop,TS val 3483431758 ecr 3868697927], length 0
15:59:20.619981 IP x.x.x.x.8080 > 133.106.52.47.65368: Flags [P.], seq 1:646, ack 598, win 505, options [nop,nop,TS val 3483431819 ecr 3868697927], length 645: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
15:59:20.621516 IP x.x.x.x.8080 > 133.106.52.47.65368: Flags [.], seq 646:1934, ack 598, win 505, options [nop,nop,TS val 3483431820 ecr 3868697927], length 1288: HTTP
15:59:20.621763 IP x.x.x.x.8080 > 133.106.52.47.65368: Flags [.], seq 1934:3222, ack 598, win 505, options [nop,nop,TS val 3483431821 ecr 3868697927], length 1288: HTTP
15:59:20.621768 IP x.x.x.x.8080 > 133.106.52.47.65368: Flags [P.], seq 3222:4510, ack 598, win 505, options [nop,nop,TS val 3483431821 ecr 3868697927], length 1288: HTTP
15:59:20.622514 IP x.x.x.x.8080 > 133.106.52.47.65368: Flags [FP.], seq 4510:5152, ack 598, win 505, options [nop,nop,TS val 3483431821 ecr 3868697927], length 642: HTTP
```

- What I got
  you can see the access from Internet was not blocked.
  any one can help?

Comment: Just in case can you provide the full network state? `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` and also `iptables-save -c`? `ss -tnlp sport == 8080` could help too.

Comment: Also just in case (though I don't see how this would affect this case): `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged` (an error or 0 is fine, 1 might cause problems).